# Can I consume a non-reactive REST API service using the Spring 5 WebFlux WebClient?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive

I have a written a microservice using Spring 5 WebFlux and trying to consume a non-reactive REST API through it. Is it possbile to consume a non-reactive service using a reactive webclient?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is possible. From the server's point of view, this is just a regular HTTP client. `WebClient` does support streaming and backpressure, but this doesn't change things at the HTTP level.

The backpressure is dealt with at the TCP flow-control level, so the HTTP protocol stays the same.